# Node.js Pass values from view to controller with a form submission

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller

When I submit my form I can't access the value of my hidden field from the controller in req.body.  However if i change it to post i can.

View

```
<form action="chat" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="user2" value="Bob">
    <input type="submit" value="Message" action="welcome">
</form>
```

Controller

```
getChat : function(req, res) {
  Message.getAllChatMessages(req.user.local.name, req.query.user2, function(err, messages, target) {
    if (err){
      return next(err);
    }
    else {
      res.render("chat", {
      messages:messages,
      title:"Private Chat",
      target:req.query.user2});
    }
  });
},
```

routes.js

```
app.get("/chat", wall_controller.getChat);
```

Comment: are you using expressjs?

Comment: yes i am using expressjs

Comment: Can you show the code on how the controller is being routed?

Comment: i just added it as an edit

Comment: Okay the problem is get cannot pass an input type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mis-understading how the method **GET** works.

**GET** uses `querystrings` and a `hidden input` cant create a query string. If you want to use a `hidden input` then you'll have to use the method **POST**.

I recommend you use **POST**, but if you really want to use **GET**. This simple fix should work:

```
// this should simply be a link
<form action="/chat?user2=Bob" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Message" action="welcome">
</form>
```

Then you can access the parameter with:

```
req.param('user2')
```

Rendering:

```
res.render("chat", {
    messages : messages,
    title    : "Private Chat",
    target   : req.param('user2')
});
```

Comment: My problem is that I need to access that variable so that I can build a url for a server request.

Comment: @CamSonaris Yes, you should use `req.param('user2')`.

Comment: A follow up question, how can i now pass this value to my target that is being rendered?

Comment: @CamSonaris updated my answer but if you can access it with `req.params('user2')` then you can pass it that variable too.

Answer (score 0):

`req.body` is not set for `GET` requests. If you're expecting `req.body` to contain query parameter values, you need to use [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query) instead. Or you could use [`req.param()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.param) which looks up `req.body` first and then `req.query`.

Comment: A follow up question, how can i now pass this value to my target that is being rendered?